# Running IIS in debug mode

Tags: iis, .net-framework

I need to start IIS in debug mode, but I also need to run in a specific app pool (one that has .NET 4.0 and allows 32-bit apps).

When I run my app, IIS runs w3wp.exe with the following command line (according to Task Manager when you add in the command-line column):

```
-ap "WebSitePool" -v "v4.0" -l "webengine4.dll" -a \\.\pipe\iisipm[[some guid]] -h "c:\inetpub\temp\apppools\WebSitePool\WebSitePool.config" -w "" -m 0 -t 20
```

If I try to run w3wp directly with those parameters, I get no error message (and nothing in the event log) but it just gives me the usage for w3wp.exe. I've tried subsets of that command-line but I can't seem to get IIS to run with the app pool I want. I've also tried using the -s parameter to specify the site (Site ID 1), and while Task Manager will show it running with the -s 1 parameter, it doesn't appear to be running in the proper app pool.

Obviously, I want to also run it with the -debug parameter, but if I do that without specifying an app pool it gives me an error because it doesn't want to allow 32-bit apps (bad image error).

There doesn't appear to be much documentation out there on this. I couldn't find any documentation on the w3wp parameters, other than the usage info w3wp.exe itself provides.

So, to sum up, I need a way to run w3wp.exe with the -debug parameter as well as have it either run in a specific app pool or, at the very least, allow 32-bit apps to run. Thanks.

Comment: This is "programy" enough that you may have better luck asking this on StackOverflow.com. Plese do not cross post, either have a moderator move the question or delete this one and re-ask there.

Comment: even better, try [ServerFault](http://www.serverfault.com)

Comment: I considered StackOverflow, but thought it wasn't programming enough. Maybe it is. I'm happy to have it moved wherever it's most likely to get an answer.

Comment: I do not really know why you are trying to use the "-debug" parameter, when it is not even the best way of debugging applications. What kind of application is it?

Comment: I need IIS to run in debug mode to make use of a tool that tracks code execution. That tool doesn't officially support operation under IIS but users have found that it works if IIS runs in debug mode. Now if only I can get my app to work with IIS running in debug mode.

Comment: I never used debug mode in IIS. Is it the same as adding in the machine.config file : <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true"/> ? Or is it the same as  [tracing](http://www.techpaste.com/2012/05/steps-enable-debug-mode-trace-iis-7-0/) ? Or both together ?